# Why is Java Calendar reporting the incorrect date?

Tags: java, date, calendar

Could anyone let me know why the following is displaying '5' in the console when it is the 22nd today (UK)?!

```
System.out.println(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: RTFD. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH

Comment: And, as it fits for any question on `java.util.Calendar`, we should refer you to joda time.

Answer (score 12):

`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` is a constant used for various operations (and happens to be its value is `5`), you should be using:

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is `static` field used inside Calendar class, you want the following

```
calendarInstance.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

---

**See**

- [`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH)

Answer (score 3):

You need to construct a calendar instance, then use that static field to look up the day of the month.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH or any other Calendar constants are not automatically set to the date, so return their default values.

```
public final static int DAY_OF_MONTH = 5;
```